# Problems in compiling a sample CUDA program

Tags: c, cuda, terminal

I am new to compiling CUDA C programs on the Linux environment. I was using the Ubuntu 12.04 server.

I want to run the template SDK provide with GPU computing SDK

When I run template by the command

```
nvcc -o template template.cu
```

It is returning me template.cu:24: fatal error: cutil_inline.h No such file or directory

Actually the file was in the directory ~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/CUDALibraries/common/inc
The same error occurs for the file template_kernel.cu which is the same directory of template

Why this error is coming. Can any one please help me.
Is it possible to give the path for these files while launching the template program i.e, giving the include files explicity but not in the program

Comment: I'm not using CUDA under linux since version 4.0, but I think there are still `makefile`(s) building all the CUDA samples for you by a simple `make`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're having problems because that is not how you build the sample programs.

Based on your description, it appears to you are using a CUDA version prior to CUDA 5.0.

Refer to the file `~/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/docs/CUDA_SDK_Release_Notest.txt` section "I. (b) Linux Installation Instructions",  to learn how to build the sample programs.

As @JackOLantern indicates, you should be using the supplied `Makefile`

Comment: Actually I was learning CUDA, I found the above command from a video lectures in udacity site, and followsed it

Comment: I just built all the binaries then is it enough with the help of the command ./prgm_bin_file will produce the correct results.....